# Optimize "if" function by row of data frame in R

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R if with vectorized statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042413/r-if-with-vectorized-statements)

there's some similar questions on how to best vectorize functions on here, but I can't yet find an example that applies an if-type function, by row for a data frame.

Give a data frame, df, with column "Year", which holds year values from 1912 - 2010, I simply want to apply a test of whether a given year is before or after a test year (e.g 1948) and assign a character "yes" or "no" in another column. Should be easy...

Currently, I have written the code as follows:

```
i = 1
while (i < nrow(df)) {
     if (df$Year[i] < 1948) {
         df$Test[i] <- "Yes"        
     } else { df$Test[i] <- "No"
     }
     i = i + 1
 }
```

The above works, but is slow with large datasets, and I know that there must be a more "elegant" solution for this in R. Would a better approach use apply? Or is there something even simpler?

Thanks!

Comment: The *See Also* section of `?"if"` tells you to look at `ifelse`, which does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `ifelse()` instead, it is vectorized and `returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the element of test is TRUE or FALSE`, or so says the help page.

For example:

```
> years <- 1980:2000

> ifelse(years < 1986, "old", "young")
 [1] "old"   "old"   "old"   "old"   "old"   "old"   "young" "young" "young" "young" "young" "young" "young" "young" "young"
[16] "young" "young" "young" "young" "young" "young"
```

You can even nest `ifelse()` statements if you have more than 2 conditions, similar to Excel if you're familiar with `=IF()`

```
ifelse(years < 1986, "old", ifelse(years < 1996, "medium", "young"))
```

Answer (score 4):

`ifelse` makes more sense here.

```
df$Test <- ifelse(df$Year < 1948, "Yes", "No")
```

`ifelse` is a vectorized version of the if/else construct.  When using R it almost always makes more sense to go with a vectorized solution if it's possible.