# Vectorized IF statement combined with logic AND in R

Tags: r, if-statement, logic, vectorization

This is my code I wish to have:

```
a=1
b=c(2,1.5,0.7)

if (a==1 & b<1) {

     b=1   # but here's the problem, that only the first value of the vector b is considered

}  # end if loop

print(b)
```

Okay, I could also write this code like this but I hope I can prevent it with your help.

```
a=1
b=c(2,1.5,0.7)

if (a==1) {

     for (i in 1:length(b)) {

          if (b[i]<1) {

               b[i]=1  

          }  # end if loop

     }  # end for loop 

}  # end if loop

print(b)
```

I also have found this question [Vectorized IF statement in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042413/vectorized-if-statement-in-r) but I cannot transfer it to my issue...

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for `as.integer(a == 1 & b < 1)`?

Comment: `if (a==1) b <- pmax(b, 1)`

Comment: BTW `if` is not a loop. Correct you could write `# end of the then-block`

Comment: @jogo: that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @tmfmnk: when I put this in my if-statement, the condition has length greater than 1 but only the first element of the vector b is used. So the problem remains - I hope I interpreted your comment right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b <- ifelse(a==1 & b<1, 1, b)
```