# dplyr create a new column with a complex user defined function of other columns

Tags: r, dplyr, user-defined-functions

I have a large data frame with responses to 40 questions (reprex with 3 questions below) and need to compute a new column that is a complex function of these 40 responses. As it is virtually impossible to write out the function within `mutate`, I tried creating a function `f` that could be used within `mutate`

```
df <- data.frame(Sex = c(rep("F", 5), rep("M", 5)),
                 Q1  = sample(0:10, 10, replace=T),
                 Q2  = sample(0:10, 10, replace=T),
                 Q3  = sample(0:10, 10, replace=T)
)

f <- function(q1, q2, q3){
  y <- q1 + (q2^2) - (q3^3)
  return(y)
}
```

Now creating a new column using `mutate` works fine.:

```
df %>%
   mutate(newcol = f(Q1, Q2, Q3))

  Sex Q1 Q2 Q3 newcol
1    F 10  6  3     19
2    F  0  9  9   -648
3    F  8  1  2      1
4    F  0  4  7   -327
5    F  6  4  1     21
6    M  8  3  3    -10
7    M  2  2  0      6
8    M 10  0  3    -17
9    M  6  9  3     60
10   M  1  7  2     42
```

as does

```
 df$newcol <- mapply(f, df$Q1, df$Q2, df$Q3)
```

But if I include even a simple `if` atatement in `f` as follows

```
f <- function(q1, q2, q3){
  y <- q1 + (q2^2) - (q3^3)
  if(y<0){
    y <- -y
  }
  return(y)
}
```

I immediately have a disaster on my hands:

```
df %>%
+   mutate(newcol = f(Q1, Q2, Q3))
   Sex Q1 Q2 Q3 newcol
1    F 10  6  3     19
2    F  0  9  9   -648
3    F  8  1  2      1
4    F  0  4  7   -327
5    F  6  4  1     21
6    M  8  3  3    -10
7    M  2  2  0      6
8    M 10  0  3    -17
9    M  6  9  3     60
10   M  1  7  2     42
Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` input `newcol`.
i the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
i Input `newcol` is `f(Q1, Q2, Q3)`.
```

However,

```
df$newcol <- mapply(f, df$Q1, df$Q2, df$Q3)
df
   Sex Q1 Q2 Q3 newcol
1    F 10  6  3     19
2    F  0  9  9    648
3    F  8  1  2      1
4    F  0  4  7    327
5    F  6  4  1     21
6    M  8  3  3     10
7    M  2  2  0      6
8    M 10  0  3     17
9    M  6  9  3     60
10   M  1  7  2     42
```

continues to work.
Unfortunately, there are lots of if's in my function, and with 40 different arguments to pass to the function, the input to mapply becomes enormous. How can I pass my questions to mapply using a predefined vector, say something like

```
questions <- c("df$Q1", "df$Q2", "df$Q3") 
df$newcol <- mapply(f, questions)
```

Closely related: How do I define a function with 40 arguments without it running off the page?

It's enitrely possible that I am barking up the wrong tree, and if so, how ought I to go about solving my problem?

Many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

P.S. Here is the real criterion

```
if(!is.na(df[i, "Q1_Daily_Mean"]) & df[i, "Q1_Daily_Mean"] >= THRESHOLD_MDD_GAD){
  anxiety <- TRUE
}

if(!is.na(df[i, "Q2_Daily_Mean"]) & df[i, "Q2_Daily_Mean"] >= THRESHOLD_MDD_GAD){
  worry <- TRUE
}

if(anxiety && worry){
  anxiety_and_worry <- TRUE
}

if(!is.na(df[i, "Q3_Daily_Mean"]) & df[i, "Q3_Daily_Mean"] >= THRESHOLD_MDD_GAD ){
  agitation <- TRUE
}

if(!is.na(df[i, "Q10_Daily_Mean"]) & df[i, "Q10_Daily_Mean"] >= THRESHOLD_MDD_GAD ){
  anger <- TRUE
}

if(!is.na(df[i, "Q2_Weekly"]) & df[i, "Q2_Weekly"] >= THRESHOLD_MDD_GAD ){
  physical_fatigue <- TRUE
}

if(!is.na(df[i, "Q5_Weekly"]) & df[i, "Q5_Weekly"] >= THRESHOLD_MDD_GAD ){
  no_concentration <- TRUE
}

if(!is.na(df[i, "Q7_Weekly"]) & df[i, "Q7_Weekly"] >= THRESHOLD_MDD_GAD ){
  disturbed_sleep <- TRUE
}

if(!is.na(df[i, "Q13_Weekly"]) & !is.na(df[i, "Q14_Weekly"]) &
   !is.na(df[i, "Q15_Weekly"]) & !is.na(df[i, "Q16_Weekly"]) & 
   !is.na(df[i, "Q17_Weekly"]) & 
   max( df[i, "Q13_Weekly"], df[i, "Q14_Weekly"],
        df[i, "Q15_Weekly"], df[i, "Q16_Weekly"],
        df[i, "Q17_Weekly"] ) >= THRESHOLD_MDD_GAD){
  max_function  <- TRUE
}

sum_of_symptoms_7 <- anxiety + worry + agitation + anger + 
                     physical_fatigue + no_concentration + disturbed_sleep

if (anxiety_and_worry && (sum_of_symptoms_7 >= CRITERIA_NEEDED_GAD) && max_function){
  # Generalized Anxiety Disorder
  df[i, GAD_DESCRIPTPR_EML] <- TRUE
}
```

Comment: `y <- abs(y)` should fix it or use `ifelse(y < 0, -y, y)`

Comment: If the primary concern is the number of arguments (40 is indeed excessive!) consider [tidying](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) your data: have two columns, one for question number and one for response, rather than one for each question.  alternatively, you could pass your conditions as a named list, the names of the list identifying the new column names and the values of the list giving the expression to evaluate to populate the new columns

Answer (score 1):

Basically the function with `if` statements is not vectorised. You have two options.

1. Make the function vectorised (using `ifelse` or any other way) and continue using it with `mutate` like you have earlier.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% mutate(newcol = f(Q1, Q2, Q3))
```

2. If the conditions are too complex and you cannot vectorise the function use `rowwise` or `pmap` which will operate on one row at a time. This is similar to your `mapply` attempt which works.

```
df %>% mutate(newcol = pmap_dbl(list(Q1, Q2, Q3), ~f(..1, ..2, ..3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" warning is the usage of `if` in combination iwth a vector (for example, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042413/vectorized-if-statement-in-r)). `dpylr`'s `mutate` passes the "whole" vector of values to the called function, (i.e. not (row) element by element). And that's where the `if` statement was confused.

This solves your problem:

```
df <- data.frame(Sex = c(rep("F", 5), rep("M", 5)),
                 Q1  = sample(0:10, 10, replace=T),
                 Q2  = sample(0:10, 10, replace=T),
                 Q3  = sample(0:10, 10, replace=T)
)

f <- function(q1, q2, q3){
  y <- q1 + (q2^2) - (q3^3)
  y <- ifelse(y<0, -y, y)
  return(y)
} 

df %>%
  mutate(newcol = f(Q1, Q2, Q3))
```

Returns:

> ```
>    Sex Q1 Q2 Q3 newcol
> 1    F  8  6  3     17
> 2    F  6  0  0      6
> 3    F  4  5  7    314
> 4    F  9  5  7    309
> 5    F  3  5  9    701
> 6    M  1 10  5     24
> 7    M 10  5  4     29
> 8    M  4  0  3     23
> 9    M  8  4  7    319
> 10   M  3  6  3     12
> ```

Comment: In this very simple case it certainly does - thank you. But the general case has many different conditions as well as Boolean combinations of them. How can I solve the problem in general?

Comment: Can you extend your question with a MRE that fits the problem you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment above:

```
f <- function(data, conditions) {
  columnNames <- names(conditions)
  for (colName in columnNames) {
    qName <- enquo(colName)
    data <- data %>% mutate(!!qName := eval(conditions[[colName]]))
  }
  data
}

df %>% f(list(bigQ1=expression(Q1 > 7), smallQ2=expression(Q2 < 2)))
```

gives, for example,

```
   Sex Q1 Q2 Q3 bigQ1 smallQ2
1    F  2  9  9 FALSE   FALSE
2    F  2 10  6 FALSE   FALSE
3    F  9  4  9  TRUE   FALSE
4    F  1  2  8 FALSE   FALSE
5    F  5 10  2 FALSE   FALSE
6    M 10  8  3  TRUE   FALSE
7    M  4  8  0 FALSE   FALSE
8    M  3  8 10 FALSE   FALSE
9    M  5  2  6 FALSE   FALSE
10   M  8  7  4  TRUE   FALSE
```

Passing the df as the first parameter of the function allows for piping.